# Sending a Protocol Buffer Message from a Java Client to C++ Server

Tags: protocol-buffers

Im trying to send a Protocol buffer message from a Java Client to a C++ Server. After runing the server and the client i just get "0" as a value for the Api field, even i set it as "1" in the Java client side.

The Java Client code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

   //the protocol buffers message is called INFO  and have only one field Api   

   INFO info = INFO.newBuilder()    

            .setApi(1)                

            .build();

   try {
   echoSocket = new Socket("localhost", 30000);
   out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: Localhost.");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: Localhost.");
        System.exit(1);
    }


    out.println((info.toByteArray())); // serialize and the message
    System.out.println("send ");
   }
   }
```

And the C++ server code looks like this:

```
int main ( int argc, int argv[] ){


INFO info;

try
 {
  // Create the socket
  ServerSocket server ( 30000 );


  while ( true )
          {


  ServerSocket new_sock;
  server.accept ( new_sock );

  try
    {


       while(true){

       std::string data;

  // in the next i'll i receive Data from the Java client i already test it with a  string, and it works 

       new_sock >> data;                  

       info.ParseFromString(data);

       cout << "api: " << info.api() << endl;             

         }
    }

  catch ( SocketException& ) {}
          }

    }
      catch ( SocketException& e )
       {
  std::cout << "Exception was caught:" << e.description() << "\nExiting.\n";
}

     return 0;
  }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I don't know if I am serializing an parsing correctly.  i didn't get any errors only a false Api value. Please let me know if you see any problems!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should add debug messages to check if you are really receiving as many bytes as you are sending. I don't think that "new_sock >> data;" is working correctly with line breaks and '\0' characters.
ProtoBuf messages don't contain information about the own length. When you send them over a raw socket you have to tell the other side first the length of the following message. You should have a look to protobufs CodedInputStream and CodedOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with:

```
new_sock >> data;
```

Verify that the number of bytes read in for `data` is the same as the size of `info.toByteArray()`. My guess is they're different, in which case you need to change the way that you're `read(2)`ing data from `new_sock` (newline delimited IO by default?).